# Iconography: How to define the "lexical level"?

Tags: icons, semiotics

With respect to symbols or icons, the *conceptual level* is defined as the viewer's mental model; the *semantic level* is the meaning it conveys; the *syntactic level* is attributed to its esthetic quality or its arrangement on the screen.

How would you describe the *lexical level* in the context of iconography?

Answer (score 1):

**Lexical level** - related with vocabulary.

The lexical system has its internal structure. It consists of a network of formal, structural and functional dependencies occurring between individuals in the lexical system of a given language.

The icon itself is not a word but a visual image.

I think that the lexical dimension can strengthen the message and assure the user in the semantic / semantic dimension.

[image]

---

I recommend reading:

https://medium.com/@wenting_zhang/getting-fluent-at-the-language-of-iconography-3415d03d0a8f

More scientifically:

http://www.cnbc.cmu.edu/~plaut/papers/pdf/Plaut97LCP.structure.pdf